# Applying the AND operator on double conditions

Tags: python

I'm trying to apply the AND operator to observe double conditions in python but it doesn't seem to be working as expected. Here is an example;

```
ylist=[(u'it', u'is'), (u'speak', u'of'), (u'of', u'school')]
slist=['it', 'is', 'of', 'not']

[x for x in ylist if (x[0] and x[1]) not in slist]

output:[(u'of', u'school')]

Expected output:[(u'speak', u'of'),(u'of', u'school')]
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `any` to reduce the not contains test for each item in the tuple:

```
>>> ylist=[(u'it', u'is'), (u'speak', u'of'), (u'of', u'school')]
>>> slist=['it', 'is', 'of', 'not']
>>> [x for x in ylist if any(e not in slist for e in x)]
[(u'speak', u'of'), (u'of', u'school')]
```